# R modify a program for our own needs

Tags: r

I am using the `gs` function provided in the `bnlearn` package. The `dput(gs)` is provided below.

```
function (x, cluster = NULL, whitelist = NULL, blacklist = NULL, 
    test = NULL, alpha = 0.05, B = NULL, debug = FALSE, optimized = TRUE, 
    strict = FALSE, undirected = FALSE) 
{
    bnlearn(x = x, cluster = cluster, whitelist = whitelist, 
        blacklist = blacklist, test = test, alpha = alpha, B = B, 
        debug = debug, optimized = optimized, strict = strict, 
        undirected = undirected)
}
```

I am wondering how I can change `gs` to be suited for my own needs. For example, I would like to increase the `alpha` value from 0.05 to 0.15.

Comment: You may want to read [Introduction to R](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), especially Section 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just default values so that you can call `gs(x)` without specifying the other parameters.
To modify alpha, simply do:

```
gs(x, alpha=0.15)
```